# Is "empty set" an element of a set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Is "empty set" an element of a set? For example:

Is this false?:

$\emptyset\in \{1,2,3\}$

Comment: What exactly is making this difficult for you? Do you know that if $a\in {b,c,d}$ then either $a=b$ or $a=c$ or $a=d$?

Comment: The empty set is a *subset* of every set including itself, but it is not necessarily an *element* of any particular set.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The empty set *can* be an element of a set, but will not necessarily always be an element of a set.

E.g.

$\emptyset \in \{\emptyset, \{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$

$\emptyset \in \{\emptyset, 1, 2\}$

$\emptyset \in \{A\}$ when $A=\emptyset$

There exist many sets though which the empty set is not a part of:

$\emptyset\not\in \{1,2,3\}$

$\emptyset\not\in \{x,y\}$

$\emptyset\not\in \emptyset$

$\emptyset\not\in\{\{\emptyset\}\}$

What will be true however is that the empty set is always a *subset of* (*different than being an element of*) any other set.

$\emptyset \subseteq \{1,2,3\}$

$\emptyset\subseteq \{a,b\}$

---

Additional details spawned from conversation in comments.

$\emptyset$ is the unique set with zero elements.  $\{\emptyset\}$ is a set with one element in it, the element namely being the emptyset.  Since $\{\emptyset\}$ has an element in it, it is not empty.  $\emptyset\neq \{\emptyset\}$

A set $A$ is a subset of another set $B$, written $A\subseteq B$, if and only if for every $a\in A$ you must also have $a\in B$.  In other words, there is nothing in the first set that is not also in the second set.

Here, we have $\{\emptyset\}\not\subseteq \{1,2,3\}$ since there is an element of the set on the left, namely $\emptyset$, which is not an element of the set on the right.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Last question: is this TRUE: `{0} ⊆ {1,2,3}` ?

Comment: But {0} ⊆ {1,2,3} is the same thing as 0 ⊆ {1,2,3}, right ?

Comment: @user284982 $\emptyset \neq \{\emptyset\}$. $\{\emptyset\}$ is not empty, because it contains $\emptyset$.

Comment: @EricTressler, therefore  {0} ⊆ {1,2,3} is false ?

Comment: @Lookbehindyou you can, in which case it is the one element set containing the element the empty set.  @ user, what does it mean to be a subset of?  Are all elements of $\{\emptyset\}$ also elements of $\{1,2,3\}$?  In other words, is $\emptyset$ an element of $\{1,2,3\}$?

Comment: @JMoravitz, nope, and  {0} ⊆ {1,2,3} is false! :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "It depends".  Some sets have the empty set as a member, other sets (like the example) you have given it isn't a member.

Answer (score 2):

$\emptyset$ is a member of some sets, not of others. It is a member of $\{\emptyset\}$, for example. It is *not* a member of $\{1,2,3\}$ — which one of $1,2,3$ is $\emptyset$? (answer: none of them). It IS a subset of every set.